functors preserve isomorphism of direct sum.
In this proof in the Stacks project, it is mentioned that the decomposition of identity morphism of direct sum:

... because the composition $F(A) \oplus F(B) \xrightarrow{\varphi} F(A \oplus B) \xrightarrow{\psi} F(A) \oplus F(B)$ is the identity map.

My question is, how do we get $\varphi$ and $\psi$, and is $\psi \circ \varphi$ really $Id_{F(A) \oplus F(B)}$ ?
My attempt: Based on the universal property of $A \oplus B$ as a direct sum, we have $i_{A}, i_{B}, p_{A}, p_{B}$, so we have $F(i_{A}): F(A) \rightarrow F(A \oplus B)$ and $F(i_{B}): F(A) \rightarrow F(A \oplus B)$. So, based on the universal property of $F(A) \oplus F(B)$ as a coproduct, we have $F(A) \oplus F(B) \rightarrow F(A \oplus B)$. Is this $\varphi$? Similarly, based on the universal property of $F(A) \oplus F(B)$ as a product, we have $F(A \oplus B) \rightarrow F(A) \oplus F(B)$. Is this $\psi$? Finally, I am unable to obtain any properties about $\psi \circ \varphi$.
Thanks for any help.

Yes, this is how you obtain $\varphi$ and $\psi$. To show they compose to the identity, we only need to check the induced maps $F(A_i)\rightarrow F(A_j)$, given by $p_{F(A_j)}\circ\psi\circ\varphi\circ \iota_{F(A_i)}$, equal $\delta_{ij}$, where $A_1=A$, $A_2=B$, and $\delta_{ij}$ is the identity if $i=j$ and zero otherwise. Maps between direct sums in an additive category are determined by the associated "matrices" of maps between their factors.
This follows essentially by definition. The map $F(A_i)\rightarrow F(A_j)$ is the composition $F(p_{A_j})\circ F(\iota_{A_i}) = F(p_{A_j}\circ \iota_{A_i}) = F(\delta_{ij}) = \delta_{ij}$.

But in the Stacks Project, we still need $i_{F(A_{1})} \circ p_{F(A_{1})} + i_{F(A_{2})} \circ p_{F(A_{2})} = Id$. Refer to here.

I'm not sure what your question is. We aren't checking that $F(A)\oplus F(B)$ is a direct sum, this is automatic. It is also true that $p_{A_j}\circ\iota_{A_i}$ is the identity map $A_i\rightarrow A_i$ if $i=j$ and zero otherwise.

Why can we deduce identity with $p_{F(A_{i})} \circ \psi \circ \varphi \circ i_{F(A_{j})} = \delta_{ij}$?

For any map $f:A_1\oplus\cdots\oplus A_m \rightarrow B_1\oplus\cdots\oplus B_n$, the induced maps $f_{ij}:A_i\rightarrow B_j$ determine $f$, where $f_{ij}=p_j\circ f\circ \iota_i$. This follows from the identity $f = \sum_{i,j} \iota_j\circ f_{ij}\circ p_i$, which in turn follows from distributivity and the identity you mentioned above, $\sum_i \iota_i \circ p_i = \mathrm{id}$. This generalizes that maps $k^m\rightarrow k^n$, for $k$ a field (or ring) are given by matrices.
